# Ansible: trying to put conditionals on a vars file

Tags: ansible, library, conditional

I'm working on a project that will use a number of devices that will need to be configured with the same plays, but separate variables. I have a vars file which includes a number of libraries, one for each device. The name of the library matches the name of the device, for example:

(Device1)

```
- {xxx: "AAA", yyy: "BBB", zzz: "CCC"}
- {xxx: "AAA", yyy: "BBB", zzz: "CCC"}
```

(Device2)

```
- {xxx: "AAA", yyy: "BBB", zzz: "CCC"}
- {xxx: "AAA", yyy: "BBB", zzz: "CCC"}
```

The play itself is supposed to figure out which library matches the device, use that library's variables and none of the other ones. My current attempt is done like this:

```
- name: do this
  command: "do some of item.xxx with some item.zzz
- include_vars: device-library.yaml
  when: "{{item}} == {{ansible_hostname}}"
```

But I always get:

> fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! 'item' is undefined"}

When this project was just one device, we used `with_items: stuff.yaml` all the time and it worked just fine.

My question is this: what do I have to put in place of `{{item}}`, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 7):

From this statement:

> The play itself is supposed to figure out which library matches the device, use that library's variables and none of the other ones.

I conclude you are trying to replicate one of the most fundamental features of Ansible.

What you should do:

1. create a subdirectory `host_vars` in your Ansible project directory;
2. move the files containing variable definitions to the `host_vars` directory;
3. make sure the above file names match exactly the host names used by Ansible to refer to the target machines (no `.yaml` extension);
4. delete all manual include directives from your playbook;
5. run the playbook.

Alternatively to cover several servers you can do the same using `group_vars` subdirectory and name the files according to the group names defined in the inventory file.

Refer to [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data) for more information.